# Comunicar Arduino por serial a través de un programa C

Tags: c++, arduino, puertos

Aquí dejo un código muy simple de `Arduino`, con 1 enciende un led y 0 apaga el led.

```
void setup(){
    pinMOde(led,OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);//iniciem el port serie
    //led.begin(16,2);
    //led.setCursor(0,0)
    //led.print("El led esta encendido?");
}
void loop(){
    Serial.println("Introduce un 0 para apagado, un 1 para encendido");
    while(Serial.available()==0); // Espera recibir datos
    int variable=Serial.read()='0'; // Leemos el puerto serie, lee a traves del codigo ASCII
    if(variable == 0){
        Serial.println("El led esta apagado");
        digitalWrite(led,LOW);
    }else if(variable == 1){
        Serial.println("El led esta encendido");
        digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
    }
    else{
        Serial.println("No funciona el led");
    }
    Serial.flush(); //serveix per eliminar el cache
}
```

Ahora adjunto un codigo en `C` muy simple a ver si pueden ayudarme a que se comunique con el `Arduino` y reciba la información.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define cport_nr=3,
#define bdrate=9600;
int C=0,A=0;
int File = 0;
File=fopen("COM3","w");
printf("Para abrir el archivo");
printf("Para encender el motor1");
scanf("%d",&C);
if (c==1){
    printf("El motor esta encendido %d",C);
}else if( A == 0){
    printf("El motor esta apagado %d",A);
}
return 0;
```

Dejo otro código con el cual estoy trabajando donde defino los bits de entrada, salida y paridad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
//DCB    dcbSerialParams ;
//GetCommState( hSerial, &dcbSerialParams.dcb);
if (!GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams.dcb)) 
{
    printf("error de estado \n");
}

dcbSerialParams.dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams.dcb); //añadimos las porpiedades del puerto


dcbSerialParams.dcb.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
dcbSerialParams.dcb.ByteSize = 8;
dcbSerialParams.dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
dcbSerialParams.dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;

dcbSerialParams.dcb.fBinary = TRUE;
dcbSerialParams.dcb.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE;
dcbSerialParams.dcb.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE;
dcbSerialParams.dcb.fOutxCtsFlow = FALSE;
dcbSerialParams.dcb.fOutxDsrFlow = FALSE;
dcbSerialParams.dcb.fDsrSensitivity= FALSE;
dcbSerialParams.dcb.fAbortOnError = TRUE;

if (!SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams.dcb)) 
{
    printf(" error setting serial port state \n");
}


GetCommTimeouts(hSerial,&timeouts);
//COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = {0};

timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 50;
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier= 10;

if(!SetCommTimeouts(hSerial, &timeouts)) 
{
    printf("error setting port state \n");
}
dwBytesRead = 0;
nread = strlen(words);

if (!ReadFile(hSerial, buffRead, nread, &dwBytesRead, NULL)) 
{
    printf("error reading from input buffer \n");
}
printf("Data read from read buffer is \n %s \n",buffRead);


CloseHandle(hSerial);
```

Comment: Te recomiendo editar la pregunta y sustituir las capturas por texto. El código de las imágenes no se puede copiar y dificilmente podrá usarse para analizar el problema.

Comment: Las fotos no se pueden copiar-pegar, ni compilar. Eso si, pueden servirnos para criticar tu elección de colores.

Comment: Ignoro si has leído al respecto, pero el puerto serie no se trata de abrirlo y empezar a enchufarle datos... hay que configurarlo para que ambos extremos usen **exactamente** la misma configuración. ¿Cual es la configuración del puerto en el lado Arduino?

Comment: Lo único que veo ahí es la tasa de datos (9600) pero ni rastro del bit de paridad, bit de stop, o tamaño de la trama... Y por cierto, el código que has puesto no es C++ sino C. Una cosa es que el código sea compatible con C++ pero desde luego no es C++...

Comment: Sigue faltando la configuración a aplicar en el puerto serie...

Comment: Como podría ser esa configuración? He de aplicar un método ASCII? No lo entiendo, ayuda por favor.

Comment: Lo primero que puedes hacer es abrir el puerto con un programa comercial (si estás en windows con el terminal). Con esa prueba garantizas que la capa arduino funciona correctamente. ¿Esa prueba funciona correctamente?

Answer (score 1):

Problemas con el código en Arduino:

```
int variable=Serial.read()='0';
```

es ilegal en C. Lo correcto es:

```
int variable=Serial.read();
```

Cuando escribes el valor 1 en el Serial Monitor, lo que Arduino recibe es el caracter 1 (decimal 51), no el valor entero correspondiente. Además, a continuación te envia un '\r', que tienes que descartar. O sea, tienes que comparar contra '1' y '0', no contra 1 y 0.

El programa correcto es este:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);//iniciem el port serie
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Introduce un 0 para apagado, un 1 para encendido");
  
  while (Serial.available() == 0); // Espera recibir datos
  
  int variable = Serial.read() = 0; // Leemos el puerto serie, lee a traves del codigo ASCII
  
  if (variable == '0') {
    Serial.println("El led esta apagado");
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  } else if (variable == '1') {
    Serial.println("El led esta encendido");
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  }
  
  Serial.flush(); //serveix per eliminar el cache
}
```